# unselected options in select box does not append into another select box

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I have 2 select boxes in my application. Now what happens that when the user submits the page, all students that have been selected (highlighted) in select box `#studentadd` gets appended to `#studentselect` select box. But options which have not been selected in the first select box would not get appended to the second select box.

My question is how can I also get unselected options within '#studentadd' select box to be appended into '#studentselect' select box?

Is the issue with my php/ajax because what I do is use ajax to navigate to the seperate php file and insert the students in the `#studentadd` select box into the database. But the insert only occur for those students highlighter in the `#studentdd` select box. It does not perform inserts on those options where were not selected in `#studentadd'.

Below is the select box `#studentadd`:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="addtextarea" id="studentadd" size="10">
    <option value='1'>u08743 - Joe Cann</option>
    <option value='4'>u03043 - Jill Sanderson</option>
    <option value='7'>u08343 - Craig Moon</option>
</select>
```

Below is the select box the students should be appended into:

```
<select id="studentselect" name="studenttextarea"></select>
```

Below is jquery/ajax:

```
 function submitform() {    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatestudentsession.php",
data: { 
    addtextarea:$('#studentadd').val()
        },
        dataType:'json',  //get response as json
        success: function(result){
                    if(result.errorflag){

       //do your stuff on getting error message
      var newHtml="<span style='color: red'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
      $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here

      $('#targetdiv').show();

    }else{
       //you got success message

       var newHtml="<span style='color: green'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
            $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);


           //append students you want to add to assessment into student exist select box 
            var selectedOption = $('select#studentadd');
            $('select#studentselect').append(selectedOption.html()); 

             //blank #studentadd select box
             $('#studentadd').empty(); 

                $('#targetdiv').show();
        }
    }
  });        
}
```

Below is the separate php file `updatestudentsession.php` which gets accessed from the ajax and inserts the data into the database:

```
$studentid = (isset($_POST['addtextarea'])) ? $_POST['addtextarea'] : array(); 
$sessionid = (isset($_POST['Idcurrent'])) ? $_POST['Idcurrent'] : array();   

$insertsql = "
INSERT INTO Student_Session
(SessionId, StudentId)
VALUES
(?, ?)
";

if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql))
{
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}      

$success = true;

foreach($studentid as $id)
{ 
    $insert->bind_param("ii", $sessionid, $id);

    if($insert->execute() === false)
    {
        $success = false;
    }
}

$insert->close();

if($success)
{
    echo json_encode(array('errorflag'=>false,'msg'=>"Students have been successfully added into the Assessment"));
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array('errorflag'=>true,'msg'=>"An error has occured, Students have not been added into the Assessment"));
}
```

Comment: Is that not expected behaviour? And why not fix that on the server?

Comment: @mplungjan The php insert seems fine in what it is doing. But I am not sure but when posting data to use for insert, does it only post select options from the select box? I want to post unselected options in select box as well. Virtually what I want is any options in `#studentadd` select box should be appended into second select box and be inserted into db, doesn't matter if selected (highlighted) in the select box or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you want to select all the target options on submit:

```
function submitform() {    
  $('#studentadd option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

or did you mean

```
  $('#studentselect option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

??

Comment: #studentadd, that is very clever thinking. Thank you for your answer :)